# Don Syme F# demo of soccer balls rolling in a 3D parabola

Tags: f#, 3d

Does anybody have a link to the Don Syme F# demo showing soccer balls rolling in a 3D parabola?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm,

http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/dan/c9-bytes-data-visualization-and-fsharp-with-luke-hoban

has a teeny bit of it at the end... where is that other video...

Aha:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uyW4WZgwxJE

about 23 minutes in.

The sample is here:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/fsharpsamples